# Calling PHP GD functions in a loop

Tags: php

I have written a php script to produce texted images on-the-fly. A demo image produced by the script is given below. As you can see to write text on the image, I have called imagettfbbox, imagefilledrectangle and imagettftext a number of times (code redundancy). Now, I would like to call these functions in a loop, producing each line of text and background rectangular image. I want to use a complete sentence broken down into several words. Each line I try to write on an image must contain four or fewer words. Is it doable? I need some insights from you fellow php experts.[image]

Here is the script

```
<?php
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('green.jpg');
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

    // Path to our font file
    $fontfile = 'theboldfont.ttf';

    // First we create our bounding box for the first text
    $bbox = imagettfbbox(30, 0, $fontfile, 'Unfortunately we never know');

    // Work out the width and height of the text
    $right_text = $bbox[2];     // right co-ordinate
    $left_text = $bbox[0];      // left co-ordinate
    $width_text = abs($right_text - $left_text);        // how wide is it?
    $height_text = abs($bbox[7] - $bbox[1]);            // how tall is it?

    // Position the text
    // Work out a base position for the start of the text
    // This is the midpoint of the available space

    $width_image = imagesx($im);
    $height_image = imagesy($im);

/*  $x = $width_image/2 - $width_text/2;
    $y = $height_image/2 - $height_text/2; */

    $x = $bbox[0] + ($width_image / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2);
    $y = $bbox[1] + ($height_image / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2);

    imagefilledrectangle($im, 
                                    $bbox[6] + ($width_image/2) - ($bbox[4]/2) - 10,        // X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle 
                                    $bbox[7] + ($height_image/2) - ($bbox[5]/2) - 10, 
                                    $bbox[0] + ($width_image / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]) + 10, 
                                    $bbox[1] + ($height_image / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2) + 10, 
                                    $red);

    // Write it
    imagettftext($im, 30, 0, $x, $y, $white, $fontfile, 'Unfortunately we never know');

    // Create the next bounding box for the second text
    $bbox = imagettfbbox(30, 0, $fontfile, "and as evidenced by many deaths");

    $x = $bbox[0] + ($width_image / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2);
    $y = $bbox[1] + ($height_image / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2) + $height_text * 2;

        imagefilledrectangle($im, 
                                    $bbox[6] + ($width_image/2) - ($bbox[4]/2) - 10,        // X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle 
                                    $bbox[7] + ($height_image/2) - ($bbox[5]/2) + $height_text +20 , 
                                    $bbox[0] + ($width_image / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]) + 10, 
                                    $bbox[1] + ($height_image / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2) + $height_text + 40, 
                                    $red);

    imagettftext($im, 30, 0, $x, $y, $white, $fontfile, "and as evidenced by many deaths");


        // Create the next bounding box for the third text
    $bbox = imagettfbbox(30, 0, $fontfile, "it without a doubt is often fatal");

    $x = $bbox[0] + ($width_image / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2);
    $y = $bbox[1] + ($height_image / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2) + $height_text * 4;


            imagefilledrectangle($im, 
                                    $bbox[6] + ($width_image/2) - ($bbox[4]/2) - 10,        // X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle 
                                    $bbox[7] + ($height_image/2) - ($bbox[5]/2) + $height_text + 80, 
                                    $bbox[0] + ($width_image / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) + ($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]) + 10, 
                                    $bbox[1] + ($height_image / 2) - ($bbox[5] / 2) + $height_text + 100, 
                                    $red);

    imagettftext($im, 30, 0, $x, $y, $white, $fontfile, "it without a doubt is often fatal");



    // Output to browser
    header ('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

The code is kind of big. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Try creating a separate function that adds text to a specified location on the image. Then you can more easily loop over calling that function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this would run the command super fast:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i < 1;$i++)
{
thefunctionyouwanttocall();
$i = 0;
}
?>
```

## Edit:

To slow the loop down do it like this:

```
<?php
for($i=1000;$i > 1;$i--)
{
if($i < 1)
{
thefunctionyouwanttocall();
$i = 1000;
}
}
?>
```